# cal extension template modification with .tmpl

Tags: html, typo3, freemarker, typoscript, extbase

I need to crop the text/characters for rendering the cal events to solve the style issues.I'm new to marker templating.Can i crop the text in .tmpl file ? or can it done with user function? How can it possible?

```
<div class="descriptif">
        <div class="objet">###CATEGORY###</div>
        <div class="titre">###TITLE###</div>
        <div class="heure">###STARTTIME###</div>
        <div class="lieu">###LOCATION###</div>
    </div>
```

I need to crop the location and the title of the event

Comment: If you have style issue it is better to fix on CSS than manipulating the data. Can you specify the issue? May be [css text-overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) will help.

Comment: I have a slicker slider.I need to render the data in that slider.When the content size vary the height of div varies

Comment: Please refer [limit-string-length-in-freemarker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394917/limit-string-length-in-freemarker) that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how to do this. Just find what the field's name is and crop it.

plugin.your_plugin {

list {

field.description = TEXT

field.description.field = description

field.description.crop = 200 | ... | 1

}

Typo3 Manual

Crops the content to a certain length.

You can define up to three parameters, of which the third one is optional. The syntax is: [numbers of characters to keep] | [ellipsis] | [keep whole words]

numbers of characters to keep (integer): Define the number of characters you want to keep. For positive numbers, the first characters from the beginning of the string will be kept, for negative numbers the last characters from the end will be kept.

ellipsis (string): The signs to be added instead of the part, which was cropped of. If the number of characters was positive, the string will be prepended with the ellipsis, if it was negative, the string will be appended with the ellipsis.

keep whole words (boolean): If set to 0 (default), the string is always cropped directly after the defined number of characters. If set to 1, only complete words are kept. Then a word, which would normally be cut in the middle, is removed completely.

Examples:

20 | ... => max 20 characters. If more, the value will be truncated to the first 20 characters and prepended with "..."

-20 | ... => max 20 characters. If more, the value will be truncated to the last 20 characters and appended with "..."

20 | ... | 1 => max 20 characters. If more, the value will be truncated to the first 20 characters and prepended with "...". If the division is in the middle of a word, the remains of that word is removed.

Uses "UTF-8" for the operation.

Comment: plugin.tx_cal_controller.view.list.event.title.crop = 20|...|1

Comment: It looks pretty good to me. Are you sure though that this is the right field? Is you title bigger that 20 letters? The |1 means that it wont crop exactly in 20 letters if the 20th letter is a part of a word, it will show the whole word and then it will crop it